# Error in execution of c file using command prompt while entering value for Scanf function

Tags: c, cmd

temp.c is the following file that has to read values entered into the command prompt while executing my c code using command lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "BlowHorn.h"
#include "BlowHorn.c"
int main()
{
    int temperature;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter the temperature value");
        scanf("%d",&temperature);
        if(temperature == 45)
        {
            continue;

        }
        BlowHorn();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

BlowHorn.h is my header file and contains following declarations in it.

```
void BlowHorn();
```

BlowHorn.c is my source file that has definitions for BlowHorn and it is as follows.

```
    void BlowHorn()
{
    printf("blow horn when temperature is not 45");
}
```

Following are my commandlines

```
D:\c\project2>gcc -o temp temp.c
D:\c\project2>temp.exe
```

the program temp.c will be executed and prints "enter the temperature value" but when a value is given and when I press enter a pop up appears showing temp.exe has stopped working.

Comment: `#include`ing source files is not a good idea.

Comment: yeah but I am using notepad++ and when i did previous project without  
#include it is showing an error for finding the other source files ...i think the problem isn't here..

Comment: What you have is a *crash*. The first step to solve it is to run a debug build (add the `-g` flag when building) in a debugger. Then the debugger will catch the crash in action and be able to tell you the location in your code where the crash happened. Also please take some time to [read about how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: yeah it is working... thankyou so much .. but where does this differ from the above case of command lines.

Comment: okay... got it..

Comment: Would anybody make an answer to this? The most interesting things seem to have been in deleted comments. Otherwise delete the now useless Q/noAnswer.

Comment: Following are the commandlines to be used



    `D:\c\project2>gcc temp.c -o temp.exe`
    `D:\c\project2>temp.exe`

It will work for these.